# Performance issue with saving NSManagedObjectContext in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm developing some text editor app on macOS with core data which is used for saving contents.

I'm facing one performance issue that typing performance gets low when I click enter key. Because the text contents are being saved(Save ManagedObjectContext) whenever user clicks enter key from keyboard.

Is there a way to save MOC in background or partially save the MOC so I can avoid the performance issue with enter key?

Any suggestions or possible solutions would be appreciated. Following is the some codes that related about this. The "**self.post**" is one object in MOC and it's being saved whenever "**[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] saveContext]**" called.

```
- (void)contentDidChangeCallback:(id)object {
    self.post.content = self.contents;

    [[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] saveContext];
}

#pragma mark - Saving
- (void)saveContext {
    NSLog(@"[%@] '%@'",self.class,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    if ([_context hasChanges]) {
        NSError *error = nil;

        if ([_context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"_context SAVED changes to persistent store");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to save _context: %@",error);
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"SKIPPED _context save, there are no changes!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the data model. How do you put the text in Core Data? Are you saving a lot of data on typing Enter? How much data is the text?

Comment: @Willeke I've added some codes to my question. The data model is somewhat complicated.

Comment: @Willeke Is there any way to save only specific object in MOC? I guess not. Let me know If you need more information.

Comment: What is the store type?

Comment: Storetype is SQLlite. I wonder that this issue could be resolved by using separate context only for the editor content and then merge with main context.

Comment: When is `contentDidChangeCallback` called? What is `self.contents`? What type is `content` (of `self.post.content`)?

Comment: contentDidChangeCallback is called whenever user press enter key on TextEditor. And self.contents means contents on TextEditor. The type of contents is NSString and the self.post.content type is also NSString. And self.post is one object in ManagedObjectContext. BTW Thank you so much for your attention and time.

Comment: Use Instruments to check where the delay is, Core Data or somewhere else. Maybe performance is better when the text is in a separate entity. [Core Data Programming Guide, Performance, Binary Large Data Objects (BLOBs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH25-SW1).

Comment: @Willeke I really appreciate for your help. Thank you so much! I will try!.